# Tratando erro na função callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando tratar um erro do seguinte código:

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('dados/arqui2vo.json', (err, data) => {

    if (err) throw new Error(`Can't find the file`)
```

Quando eu vou rodar o código, essa mensagem aparece no console:

```
c:\Users\<User>\Documents\Node\readFile.js:5
if (err) throw new Error(`Can't find the file`)
         ^

Error: Can't find the file
    at ReadFileContext.fs.readFile [as callback] (c:\Users\<User>\Documents\Node\readFile.js:5:20)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)
```

Como posso mostrar a mensagem de erro que criei? Essa é a mensagem que gostaria que aparecesse no meu console:

```
Error: Can't find the file
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/406786/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Comment: Até agora você não editou sua pergunta. Nosso colega avisou para você e não há edição nela. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro mostrado no terminal está sendo criado na seguinte linha:

> ```
> if (err) throw new Error('Can\'t find the file');
> ```

Note que você não está tratando o erro da forma mais usual, uma vez que está **criando um novo erro** (`throw new Error`), que provavelmente não será tratado em um outro momento, o que irá emitir um erro no terminal, conforme você relatou na sua pergunta.

Então, ao invés de criar um novo erro dentro do *callback*, procure somente exibir uma informação no *console*, para que você saiba que ocorreu um erro. Algo assim:

```js
if (err) {
  console.error('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar ler o arquivo.');
}
```

Desse modo, você está realizando a *devida tratativa do erro*, e o processo do Node.js continuará a ser executado normalmente, já que o erro foi propriamente tratado.

E se você quiser sair da aplicação quando ocorrer um erro, basta usar o [`process.exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code):

```js
if (err) {
  console.error('<sua mensagem de erro aqui>');
  process.exit(1);
}
```

No código acima, passamos `1` como primeiro argumento para o método `process.exit`, para indicar que um erro causou o término do processo.

---

<sup>Note que para aplicações maiores que serão usadas em um ambiente de produção, exibir somente uma mensagem de aviso pelo `console` pode não ser o suficiente. Procure pesquisar a fundo sobre como tratar um erro em produção se quiser saber mais.</sup>

Comment: Mas eu queria que parasse a execução do código nesse momento e mostrasse o tipo de erro que houve e/ou fazer uma verificação no arquivo, caso ele esteja faltando algum item, também parar a execução e mostrar que no arquivo não há tal informação.

Comment: Eu editei a minha pergunta mostrando uma solução para interromper o processo do Node.js.

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Você tem saberia me indicar uma fonte de estudo para tratar os erros de maneira mais adequada para produção?

Comment: Depende da aplicação. Fiz uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406793/armazenar-os-logs-da-minha-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-disco-%c3%a9-uma-m%c3%a1-ideia) sobre o assunto recentemente. Você também pode usar serviços mais avançados (mas que muitas vezes requerem uma assinatura), como o [Sentry](https://sentry.io) para isso... Inicialmente, usar uma biblioteca como [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) ou [Pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) pode ser uma boa ideia.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!