# Armazenar os logs da minha aplicação no disco é uma má ideia?

Tags: log

Todos sabemos a importância dos *logs* para o *debug* de uma aplicação em um ambiente de produção.

Atualmente, mantenho os *logs* em um arquivo (`/tmp/logs/app-logs.log`). O problema é que ele pode ficar pesado com o tempo, já que o número de *logs* tende a crescer junto com a aplicação.

Também penso que salvar no banco de dados da aplicação (MySQL) pode não ser muito vantajoso, já que o volume de *logs* pode ser grande e a quantidade de *queries* seria monstruosa.

A pergunta é: posso manter os *logs* da minha aplicação em um arquivo e ir o esvaziando ao longo do tempo ou existe alguma forma um pouco mais adequada para se fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, você pode fazer com que esses logs sejam "apagados" de tempo em tempo.
Eu uso com frequência o armazenamento de logs, pois se algum bug ocorre e por algum motivo desconhecido o programa fecha sem mostrar a mensagem de erro, é quase certeza que você encontrará o motivo desse bug nos logs.
Dica: Você pode checar a data de criação/edição do arquivo, e comparar com a data atual, se a diferença de dias/meses entre as datas for maior que 'n'(sendo 'n' o intervalo para reciclar esse arquivo), você apaga todo o conteúdo de dentro dele.
Abraços!